# Swarm plot with Echarts

Tags: javascript, plot, data-visualization, echarts, swarmplot

Swarmplots don't seem to exist in Echarts.

But since Echarts can be full of surprises, I was wondering if, somehow, there is a trick to make a swarm plot.

I was thinking of maybe an hidden option, or a feature that could be diverted from its original purpose. I would love to get suggestions!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scatter plot ([documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-scatter) | [basic example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=scatter-simple)).
You will probably have to format your data beforehand, but I think it'll do the job.